# How to obtain Public IP of a device using C# with out using external API/Services

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, httpcontext

```
  public static string GetPublicIp()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[0];
            }
        }
        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

I'm trying to get the client Public IP but the above code only returns the client Local IP. If different people are connecting to my organisation from the same organisations network, i want to get only their public IP address. I'm not intrested in their local IPs, is this possible.

Below is one solution i have so far seen but i'm NOT liking it.

```
public static string GetPublicIp()
{
    string direction = "";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
    using (WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        direction = stream1.ReadToEnd();
    }
    //Search for the ip in the html
    int first1 = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
    int last1 = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
    direction = direction.Substring(first1, last1 - first1);

    return direction;
}
```

The above sample solution can get me the public IP but i don't want to be tied to an external service that i have no control over because if that service is down then iam screwed and the performance is terrible.

Does any one know how i can get the clients public IP with out calling external services?

Comment: The first snippet attempts to get the client address of an *incoming* http request, while the second attempts to get the public IP of the host running the code, which is it you want?

Comment: I want to get the Public IP of an incoming http request.

Comment: If someone on a local network connects to a server on that same local network, you will not be able to determine that clients "public" ip address. Technically it could be many different IPs depending on how their route table is configured. The clients "public ip" does not really exist in the context that you are taking about.

Comment: @BenRobinson, what is the better way to handle this scenario. When some one visits my web application, i want to get their public IP, NOT their Local IP. If the application is hosted on my network and some one accesses the application from my network, i want to get the public IP of my network.

Comment: Technically "the public IP of my network" is not a thing. For every node on a private network that can access the public internet, that node's "public ip" is an ip address that belongs to the router that node has configured as their gateway for the particular IP address they are connecting to. In theory this could vary for each node on the network, for each public IP range they connect to. On small networks there is often a single router that is the gateway for all node on the network for all public internet IPs on larger networks this may be more complex.

Comment: @BenRobinson great stuff thanks. This is my first time to handle this kind of dev work. Is there away i can at-least get the ISP ip address.

Answer (score 0):

This method gives you the local ip address. I've copied it from a WinRT-Solution, maybe the class names are a bit different in other .NET environments.

```
private static string GetLocalAddress()
{
    var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
    foreach (var hn in hostnames)
    {
        //IanaInterfaceType == 71 => Wifi
        //IanaInterfaceType == 6 => Ethernet (Emulator)
        if (hn.IPInformation != null &&
            (hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71
             || hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6))
        {
            return hn.DisplayName;
        }
    }

    return IpAddress.Broadcast.Address;
}
```

EDIT: The following method prints out all local ip addresses.

```
private static void PrintLocalAddresses()
{
    var interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (var ni in interfaces)
    {
        if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet ||
            ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
        {
            var adapterProperties = ni.GetIPProperties();
            foreach (var x in adapterProperties.UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.Address);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use seem to be using Windows.Networking.Connectivity namespace which looks like is not supported in .NET 2.0

Comment: I added a second solution to my answer.

Comment: i am specifically interested in the PUBLIC IP.

Comment: They are all public ip's. If you have multiple network Interfaces (on my Computer WIFI, RJ45) then you have multiple public ip addresses.